# C how to read middle bits?

Tags: c, bit, ram, endianness

Please note my comments, the question is still unanswered.

I have the following **which I can't change**:

```
unsigned long addr=142;
u16 offset_low, offset_middle;
u32 offset_high;
```

I want to set `offset_low` for low 16 bits, `offset_middle` for mid 16 bits and `offset_high` for higher 32 bits of `addr`.

So I wrote:

```
offset_low = addr & 0xFFFF;
offset_middle = addr & 0xFFFF0000;
offset_high = addr & 0xFFFFFFFF0000;
```

Is this right? Is there any clear way to do it instead of wiriting so many F?

Why I think it's not right?

I am working with **little endian**, so when doing addr & 0xFFFF0000; I will get the mid bits but with zeros and it may load the zeros instead of non-zeroes.

Comment: The high one should have 8 `0`s, not 4, right?

Comment: `offset_middle = addr & 0xFFFF0000;` -> `offset_middle = (addr & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16;`

Comment: Endianness has nothing to do with extracting bits from integer. It is related to encoding integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your purpose you must shift the masked values:

```
unsigned long addr = 142;  // 64-bit on the target system
uint16_t offset_low = addr & 0xFFFF;
uint16_t offset_middle = (addr & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16;
uint32_t offset_high = (addr & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000) >> 32;
```

Note that since you extract exactly 16 and 32 bits to variables with the same size, masking can be omitted:

```
uint64_t addr = 142;
uint16_t offset_low = addr;
uint16_t offset_middle = addr >> 16;
uint32_t offset_high = addr >> 32;
```

The order of bytes in memory (little endian vs big endian) is irrelevant for this question. You could read the specific parts from memory using this knowledge, reading the first 2 bytes for `offset_low`, the next 2 for `offset_middle` and the next 4 for `offset_high`, but extracting from the full 64-bit value is performed the same for both architectures.

Comment: why your answer isn't similar to the other one in middle?

Comment: Please Note I can't change the declaration (which appears after I have) it's in lenux kernel

Comment: @john: masking is not needed because `offset_low` and `offset_high` have exactly 16 bits, as they are defined with type `uint16_t`, `offset_low = addr;` will extract the low 16 bits, and `offset_middle = addr >> 16;` will extract the middle 16 bits exactly. `addr >> 32` leaves only the high 32 bits of `addr`, assuming it is an unsigned 64-bit value so no mask is needed there either.

Answer (score 0):

Shifting one by desired bits and then subtracting one will give sequence of bits `1` unless you want the top (most significant) bit in the integer type to be one.

Assuming that `unsigned long` in the environment has 33 bits or more, it can be written like this:

```
offset_low = addr & ((1UL << 16) - 1);
offset_middle = (addr >> 16) & ((1UL << 16) - 1);
offset_high = (addr >> 32) & ((1UL << 32) - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is this right?

Not quite, these would be correct:

```
offset_low = addr & 0xFFFF;
offset_middle = (addr >> 16) & 0xFFFF;
offset_high = addr >> 32;
```

You didn't shift your results to the right (and your high was just wrong).

> I am working with little endian, so when doing addr & 0xFFFF0000; I will get the mid bits but with zeros and it may load the zeros instead of non-zeroes.

The endianness doesn't matter in code, because code runs on the same machine. It only matters during serialization, where you write to a stream on one machine and read from another machine of another endianness, thus getting garbage.

Comment: Why in mid you used && and didn't use it in high?

Comment: @john: masking is only needed if `offset_low` and `offset_high` have more than 16 bits, but since they are defined with type `uint16_t`, `offset_low = addr;` will extract the low 16 bits, and `offset_middle = addr >> 16;` will extract the middle 16 bits exactly. `addr >> 32` leaves only the high 32 bits of `addr`, assuming it is an unsigned 64-bit value.